# Nativescript RadListView multiple selection: how to remove default style?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using `RadListView` to create a multiple selection on **IOS**.

In front of the selection item somehow there is a circle checkbox I couldn't remove, which looks like:
[image]

My codes are:

```
<RadListView [items]="items" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="true" height="80%">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
         <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

and:

```
this.items = [{ name: 'test1' }, { name: 'test2' }, { name: 'test3' }];
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, those checkboxes appear beside your label is the only way user would distinguish between selected & unselected items.

You may apply padding only for iOS to prevent overlapping,

```
<RadListView [items]="items" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="true" height="80%">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
         <Label ios:paddingLeft="50" [text]="item.name"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

If you still prefer a different style for selection, you will have to build your own, you may have a selected flag in each data item and toggle them upon tapping list item and update your CSS (may be background-color) for list item based on the selected flag.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to build my own selection style without the checkbox. Somehow the circles just won't go away.

Comment: You are not suppose to use selectionBehavior at all if you like your own implementation.

Comment: On Android it all looked fine so I thought it would be good to use the same pattern. But I guess I'll just have to create my own implementation.

Comment: You know what, changing the background of the item on IOS would make the circle go away! Looks like the circle is a CSS background property. Thanks a lot!!